# Blender - Substance Painter Opacity Settings

Tags: node-editor

I was only able to find one other question related to this, however it did not look like it got answered.

*If this question should be for a Substance Painter forum, please let me know!

I have several screenshots - one is from Substance Painter of a sphere with a blue-tinted opacity (as well as some other dirt/dust layers). When I bring it into Blender, It is very transparent and the color doesn't seem to match up. I have several screenshots of the node setups I've tried. In one of them it is very opaque. Let me know if there is an easy solution. I am new to using substance painter to export into blender.

[image: Substance Screenshot]

[image: Blender Screenshot]

[image: Blender Screenshot]

[image: Blender Screenshot]

Comment: You'd have to make sure that you're using the pbr metal rough template to export your textures. Then just plug them into one principled shader properly and make sure you're using the same hdri if you'd like to match the appearance. However, without seeing the actual files or any accurate description of what you're trying to do it's just guessing what you might missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Substance Painter's internal renderer is using a built in HDRI.

[image]

You can see an environment reflected on the object.  You'd have to set up an HDRI environment in Blender to compare against.  There are lots of sites where you can pick up free ones.

You can implement one in your scene by switching your node viewer to *World* and using an image node set to *Equirectangular*, like this.

[image]

Or as of 2.93 there is an *Environment Texture* node.

[image]